# Other predicates that divide Integers into 2 besides odd/even?

Tags: sequences-and-series

The odd/even predicate neatly seperates the integers into 2 distinct sets with the same cardinality. What are other such patterns? I would like to use that pattern as part of a "randomized" controlled trial, to assign participants to different interventions, without a central coordinating system. So the pattern of who was in group A vs. B was more complex than alternating, but still deterministic based on $id$ of the participant.

Comment: If you think about it, any partition of the integers into two disjoint infinite subsets has the "same cardinality" property.  So integers that are divisible by 3 and those not divisible by 3 would work just as well as even vs. odd, as would primes vs. not primes, or many other ideas.  Your application seems driven by an "equal probability" of assignment, so I suspect you need to refine the "same cardinality" requirement.

Comment: what about negative and non-negative integers?